# What is M Night Shyamalan saying with the ending of Split?

Tags: split

Obviously there will be spoilers about the ending of [Split (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4972582/) so don't read further if you don't want the ending spoiled.

> At the end of the movie, there is a scene in a coffee shop where various people are commenting about the news story about Kevin being at large and how it reminds them of the other guy in the wheelchair... oh what's his name...? And then we see Bruce Willis who provides the answer, "Mr. Glass". Obviously tying Split to the movie Unbreakable.

So is this an indication that M Night is planning to build a franchise of movies based on this universe? Has he or anyone else given an indication that this is the plan or was there some other reason for this final scene?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From an [**interview**](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/m-night-shyamalan-split/) with **M. Night Shyamalan**:

> **I wrote this character [Kevin] and a bunch of the scenes you saw in
> the movie for the [Unbreakable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbreakable_(film)) script. He was the original antagonist
> and David Dunn was going to meet him in the original script.**
>
> I
> couldn’t get it right, I couldn’t get the balance right. It just kept
> wanting to eat away at the other movie. I pulled Kevin out. I wanted a
> really slow burn movie and Kevin’s not a slow burn. I said, ‘let me
> pull him out for a second and concentrate on these other two
> characters’.
>
> I came up with the idea for Elijah [Mr. Glass, the
> character played by Samuel L. Jackson in Unbreakable]. He was always
> an advisor. The three of them were always in it but he went from
> benevolent advisor to the opposite of David Dunn! It became so
> obvious.
>
> Then I said I’d do this next as the next piece in this, but I
> guess I felt that the reaction at the time was weird and wonky to
> Unbreakable, especially in the United States. ‘What is this? A movie
> about comic books?’ The studio didn’t want to sell it as comic books
> because they felt comic books were not sellable, they didn’t think
> there was an audience for it.

He is already working on continuing the story:

> **I’m writing the outline now.** It’s weird. It’s long. It’s the longest
> outline I’ve ever had. It’s almost ten pages of an outline. I don’t
> know what that means. It’s very long. It has so many characters. It’s
> a weird process.
>
> I already know all the characters, or most of them. I
> know 80% of the characters, so the discovery process isn’t there. It’s
> easy to write, which I’m very suspicious about. There’s not been a lot
> of bloodshed yet.
>
> **I hope if Split is a success, I’ll have the
> opportunity to finish the story. I want to finish it, so this is the
> third one.**

Comment: Looks like I am too slow this days :D, anyway +1, [Here](http://ew.com/movies/2017/01/20/split-m-night-shyamalan-ending-interview/?xid=entertainment-weekly_socialflow_twitter) is what I got

Comment: Third one what? Third movie? Third opporutnity to finish the movie? #confused

Comment: @Mindwin a third movie in that universe, like for example a sequel to Unbreakable, with Kevin as the big bad.

Comment: @CyberClaw I assumed "this" was refering to Split, thanks. [changing pages] Also, those movie studio execs are in another dimension, if they think there is/was no audience for comic book movies.... there might not be audience for bad movies, but those deserve the gutter anyway.

Comment: @Mindwin, Unbreakable is from 2000. It's way before comic book movies were a good thing. Heck, Marvel signed away X-Men/Fantastic Four to Fox and SpiderMan to Sony exclusively, 3 of their biggest franchises. 2002 saw the first Sony Spider-Man, which was in big part responsible for the the change in perception for these movies. That was about when Marvel execs started pulling off their hairs, and scrambling for something to work with (all there was left was the Avengers).

Comment: @CyberClaw At least Marvel has now worked out a deal with Sony that lets them use Spider-Man properly.

Comment: Sounds like Shyamalan is subtle-jabbing in that interview: "They didn't think there was a market for [comic book-related] movies." :) Well, the studio sure missed out on that one.

Comment: I was surprised at (A) they still let the guy make movies after so many of his bombs, concept-wise, and (B) how good the movie was.  Makes sense that it links back to his original concept.  Looking forward to the enentual third movie.